# How to check for :focus in input:text or textarea

Tags: jquery, html, forms, focus

is it possible to check for focus in  `input[type="text"]` and `textarea` in one call like this?

```
$("input[type='text']").focus(function() {});
```

Or would I have to create two JQuery calls to check for both types of focus?

```
$("input[type='text']").focus(function() {});
$("textarea']").focus(function() {});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use a comma, it means `OR`. Try this:

```
$("input[type='text'], textarea").focus(function() {});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
$("input[type='text'], textarea").focus(function() {});
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can combine selectors and attach a single function like so

```
$("input[type=text],textarea").focus(function() {});
```